# Efficient code for checking offset in pixel coordinates

Tags: java, performance, math

I'm making a tile-based rendering method for a game, using Java.

There is the possibility of the first row (and column) of tiles be partially drawn on screen and i want to know how many pixel of these tiles are on screen.

I came up with this (for checking the max X coordinates of broken tiles):

```
int brokenX = xOffset; //xOffset can be any number
while (brokenX < 0){
    brokenX += tileSet.getTileSize(); //corrects if the number is negative
}
while (brokenX >= tileSet.getTileSize()){
    brokenX -= tileSet.getTileSize(); //corrects if the number is too big
}
```

This works fine. But it seems like a waste of resources (considering it will be done twice for each frame).

Is there some **efficient** way (bit masks and such) of doing this?

Comment: When you observed that your frame rate was too low and profiled your application, is this bit of code what you traced the bottleneck to?

Comment: No, I was not profiling. I just checked the time before and after the  `render()` method. This was just the first part of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to use a library function. Obviously, it's an huge overkill for this task, but there's much more in a good library. My favorite is Guava and [this is](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/math/IntMath.java#L389) the `mod` method:

```
int result = x % m;
return (result >= 0) ? result : result + m;
```

An example should make it clear. I'm trying the numbers `13, 3, -7, -17` modulo `10`, which all should return the same result.

- `13 % 10 = 3`, that's OK
- `3 % 10 = 3`, still OK
- `-7 % 10 = -7` is negative and unusable as index, but with`-7 % 10 + 10 = 3` it's fine.
- `-17 % 10 + 10 = 3` is fine, too.

So for `result < 0`, or equivalently `m < 0`, you need to add `m` to get a positive result.

Comment: I don't understand. Can you explain what these expressions do please?

Comment: Now i got it! It is simple and drops 60000ns in rendering time. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for

```
brokenX = xOffset % getTileSize();
```

I think the above should work for negative also but if xOffset can be greater, then you could do

ok.. good.   I think just adding a check in the last line should fix it.

```
hiddenTiles = xOffset /  getTileSize();
xOffset -= hiddenTiles * getTileSize();
if(xOffset < 0) {
    brokenX=  -(-xOffset % getTileSize());
}
else {
    brokenX = xOffset % getTileSize();
}
```

Or as Jason suggests:
Just the one line...

```
brokenX=  (xOffset + getTileSize())% getTileSize());
```

I really think, this should work for negative offsets also. So no changes are required.

Comment: This was my first choice, but `xOffset` can be negative or greater than `tileSize`

Comment: I tried your solution. The rendering time drops from 118 to 86 ms. But it only works for positive values.

Comment: ok.. good.   I think just adding a check in the last line should fix it.
    hiddenTiles = xOffset /  getTileSize();
    xOffset -= hiddenTiles * getTileSize();
    if(brokenX < 0) {
        brokenX=  xOffset % getTileSize();
    }

Comment: If you know `xOffset > -tileSize`, which @MarlonDias seems to imply, you can just handle both cases with `brokenX = (xOffset + tileSize) % tileSize;`. The classic one liner when this condition isn't true is `brokenX = ((xOffset % tileSize) + tileSize) % tileSize;`, but the first modulo is not necessary if `xOffset > -tileSize`.

Comment: @Jason Could you please post the final code itself. Just would like to see, if that will give better performance or lesser lines of code or both or none.

Comment: @SahilBajaj I already did post the final code. `brokenX = (xOffset + tileSize) % tileSize;`. That's it. No if statements or anything.

Comment: @SahilBajaj eitanfar raises a good point in the comments on [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24349561/616460), though, that if this assumption is broken it can easily lead to a bug. So we can only use it if we're *absolutely certain* that there's no possible way `xOffset <= -tileSize`.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a common way of overcoming the negative problem in modulo without a conditional:

```
int tileSize = tileSet.getTileSize();
int brokenX = ((xOffset % tileSize) + tileSize) % tileSize;
int brokenY = ((yOffset % tileSize) + tileSize) % tileSize;
```

This works since:

1. The first modulo makes sure that the number is less than tileSize
2. The addition makes sure that the number is positive, since it was less than tileSize, and was added tileSize
3. The second modulo makes sure that the number is positive and less than tileSize again

Comment: For sure invoking `%` twice is not the fastest way. An optimal expression is about the same length.

Comment: @maaartinus Assuming that you're talking about what you wrote in your answer, it's still longer, and more importantly, less optimal in terms of cpu usage. The JVM handles modulo much more efficiently than the branching introduced by conditionals.

Comment: I rather doubt it. Quite often, the branch is predictable (as you're often guarding against negative values but don't really expect them) and so nearly free. Otherwise, a conditional move can be used. Note that the Guava guys optimize quite heavily. Anyway, a good point, someone should write a (Caliper or JMH) benchmark to resolve the dispute.

Comment: This is actually quite fast. However, you can optimize it a bit further. If you know `xOffset` will never be `<= -tileSize` (which the OP's description implies) you can do `int brokenX = (xOffset + tileSize) % tileSize;` and eliminate the first modulo (the only reason that first modulo needs to exist in the first place is to put the operand in the range [-tileSize, tileSize], exclusive). Same for Y.

Comment: @JasonC You're right of course, but I didn't make that assumption, since I've seen this turn out to be a bug too many times in the past to take that chance. Good point though.

Answer (score 0):

If tile size is a power of two you could do

```
brokenX = xOffset & (tileSize - 1);
```

Comment: By now my `tileSize` is 32, but i plan to reuse the rendering method for other sizes. Would this code work if i tried `tileSize = 48`?

Comment: No, `tileSize` has to be a power of two (..., 32, 64, 128, 256, ...)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (brokenX < 0)
    brokenX = tileSizeX - (Math.abs(brokenX) % tileSizeX);
```